# WebService Error Endpoint

Tags: windows-services, endpoint

I'm working on a project that must connect to a asmx page.

But, it throws an exception 'Endpoint not found', but I configured all my app, set all the endpoints configurations in app.config. I've tried to connect to localhost and it works.

I've also tried something like disable firewall...

What could it be? Must it have something to port configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this a deployed app, or are you running in debug mode from Visual Studio? In visual studio debug mode, you will have to set your endpoint addresses to include whatever port # the webservice starts on when you click "run" in VS (it should popup in your notifications tray). Then when you publish the project later, you will have to remember to change these endpoints back to not include the port #... That's the only thing I can think of that has tripped me up in the past. If that's not it- good luck.